# How to check if a checkbox returns a value? Error:"Notice: Undefined index:"

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I am working on my final project in my final grade.
I'm currently working on a site linked with mysql for a dance school.
I want to check if a checkbox returns a value or not.
It gives a "undefined index"-error at the "if($_POST['dansstijl'.$i.''])" and I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Sorry if there are parts in dutch!

Here's a big part of the code:

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO tblinschrijvingen(llnID) VALUES('".$lln_id."')";
   if(!$result1=$mysqli-> query($sql1))
                       {trigger_error('Fout bij query: '.$mysqli->error);}
   else 

   {
       $sql2="SELECT inschrijvingsID FROM tblinschrijvingen ORDER BY inschrijvingsID DESC LIMIT 1";
       if(!$result2=$mysqli-> query($sql2))
                       {trigger_error('Fout bij query: '.$mysqli->error);}
       else 
       {
           for($i=1;$i<=11;$i++)
           {
               if($_POST['dansstijl'.$i.''])
               {
                   $row=$result2->fetch_assoc();
                   $inschrijvingsID=$row['inschrijvingsID'];

                   $sql3="SELECT DansID, vestiging, Dansstijl FROM tbldanslessen WHERE vestiging='".$vestiging."' AND Dansstijl='".$_POST['dansstijl'.$i.'']."'";

                   echo($sql3);
                   if(!$result3=$mysqli-> query($sql3))
                           {trigger_error('Fout bij query: '.$mysqli->error);}
                   else 
                   {
                       $row=$result3->fetch_assoc();
                       $dansID=$row['DansID'];

                        $sql4="INSERT INTO tblinschrijvingenperdansles(inschrijvingsID, dansID) VALUES ('".$inschrijvingsID."', '".$dansID."')";
                        if(!$result4=$mysqli-> query($sql4))
                               {trigger_error('Fout bij query: '.$mysqli->error);}
                       else 
                       { 
                       }
                    }
               }
        }
   }
```

Here are my checkboxes:

```
<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="199"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl1" value="Peuterballet" id="dansstijl1">
      Peuterballet</label></td>
      <td width="162"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl2" value="Preballet" id="dansstijl2">
      Preballet</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl3" value="Preprimary" id="dansstijl3">
      Preprimary</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl4" value="Primary" id="dansstijl4">
      Primary</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl5" value="Klassiek" id="dansstijl5">
      Klassiek</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl6" value="Modern Jazz" id="dansstijl6">
      Modern Jazz</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl7" value="Hedendaags" id="dansstijl7">
      Hedendaags</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl8" value="Musical" id="dansstijl8">
      Musical</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl9" value="Pointes" id="dansstijl9">
      Pointes</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl10" value="Hiphop - Breakdance" id="dansstijl10">
      Hiphop - Breakdance</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dansstijl11" value="Hiphow - Crew" id="dansstijl11">
      Hiphow - Crew</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you on forehand!

Jules

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`if($_POST['dansstijl'.$i.''])`

to

`if (isset($_POST['dansstijl'.$i.'']))`

This checks whether or not the dansstijl is set, instead of trying to get the value of the dansstijl(which may not exist,thus giving you the error).

Comment: Thank you! This was pretty idiotic of me, i stared 2 hours at my screen wondering what i did wrong :p.

Comment: Geen probleem ;), we all have those moments so don't worry about it ;) .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in my humble opinion, you need to improve on the readability part of your code. You will thank yourself later if you ever have to look at the code in a couple of weeks.

Second, you are accessing POST forms in a loop by interpolating strings with numbers. You also need to debug yourself the situation by, for example, putting an echo() just after the if in order to know which index is the one you cannot access to.

Besides, code organization should be much more important to you, and divide logical units in their own functions, not as a nested tree of if-clauses.

Also, in PHP you can send fields as `<input name="hello[1]" value="x" />` and `<input name="hello[2]" value="y" />` and you can get them in `$_POST['hello'][1]` and `$_POST['hello'][2]`, see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#87650.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['dansstijl'.$i.''])) {

 // query ...
```